# Bootstrap nav-justified inside div.col-* not working as expected

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I am facing a problem with bootstrap 3 and the nav-justified class. When I put the nav inside a div with class col-*, it does not work properly. When you try to minimize the screen, if the resolution is less than 1500px the `<li>` overflows the div. I was wondering why.

I would like to know if I am missing something. Here goes an exemple of code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clickable">
        XYZ
        <span class="pull-right"><i class="fa fa-caret-up fa-lg"></i></span>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body ">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified" role="tablist" id="myPill">
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#externalio" aria-controls="home" data-toggle="tab">External I/O</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#versionInformation" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Version Information</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#configInformation" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Config Information</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#channelA" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Channel A</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#statistics" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Statistics</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#adc" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">ADC</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#samplingInfo" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Sampling Info</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#flags" aria-controls="profile" data-toggle="tab">Flags</a></li>
        </ul>
        <hr />
        <div class="tab-content" id="advancedContent">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="externalio">
                
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="versionInformation">
                
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="configInformation">
                
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="channelA">
                
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="statistics">
                
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="adc">
                
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="samplingInfo">
               
            </div>
            <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="flags">
                
            </div>
        </div>        
    </div>

</div>
</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank you.

Comment: What does *"not work properly"* mean?

Comment: When you try to minimize the screen, if the resolution is less than 1500px the <li> overflows the div.

Answer (score 0):

I have a easy solution. Use this code below:

```
@media screen and (max-width:1500px){
    .panel .nav>li>a{
         padding:5px 0;
    }
}
```